# Prove or disprove: $\lim_{x\to \infty}(f(x+\frac{1}{f'(x)})-f(x))=1$ if and only if $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{f''(x)}{(f'(x))^2}=0$.

Tags: calculus, limits

Prove or disprove: $\lim_{x\to \infty}(f(x+\frac{1}{f'(x)})-f(x))=1$ if and only if $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{f''(x)}{(f'(x))^2}=0$.

I suspect the statement is true, because every function I have considered either meets both conditions (for example, $f(x)=x^a$ for $a>0$, $f(x)=(\ln{x})^b$ for $b>1$), or fails both conditions (for example, $f(x)=2x+\sin{x}$, $f(x)=\ln{x}$).

I have tried, without success, to prove the statement using the definition of limit, differentiation from first principles, and differential equations.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming enough regularity and using Taylor's formula, you have that
$$
f(x+1/f'(x)) = f(x) + f'(x)\frac{1}{f'(x)} + \frac{f''(\xi)}{2}\frac{1}{f'(x)^2}.
$$

So,

$$
f(x+1/f'(x)) - f(x) -1 = \frac{f''(\xi)}{2 f'(x)^2},\quad \xi \in (x, x+\frac{1}{f'(x)}).
$$

Now, if we can assure that $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to \infty}\left(x+\frac{1}{f'(x)}\right)=+\infty$, the result follows. But if this condition does not hold... So, I'd look for counter-examples where
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(x+\frac{1}{f'(x)}\right)<\infty.
$$

---

Comment: Pierre, f(x) = -lnx meets the condition in the last line of your answer, but f(x) = -lnx is not a counter-example. Do you know of a counter-example?

Comment: Pierre, how do we know that epsilon approaches infinity as x approaches infinity? (By "epsilon" I mean the letter in your answer that looks like "E".)

Comment: Pierre, in the first equation of your answer, where you wrote "f(1+1/f'(x)) = ...", did you mean to write "f(x+1/f'(x)) = ..." ?

Comment: @Dan, yes, I'll correct it.

Answer (score 0):

notice that:
$$\cfrac{f''(x)}{f'(x)^2}=-\frac d{dx}\cfrac 1{f'(x)}$$
so if this limit $\to0$ then
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\cfrac{1}{f'(x)}\to c\in\mathbb{R}$$
(a constant non-divergent) we then have:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[f(x+c)-f(x)\right]$$
where $c$ will become arbitrarily small and so this tends to zero

Comment: @PierreCarre its a typo sorry

Comment: Ok, but we must be careful when exchanging limits and derivatives... It is something known to fail in some circunstances.

Comment: Henry, have you considered f(x) = x^(1/2) ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof of the "if" part of the statement (not the "only if" part).

[image: Proof]